# Highcharts xAxis on drilldown chart not displaying properly

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm having issues with a highcharts chart. I have three levels, with three separate x axes defined in the code. When I drilldown from the first level to the second level, the x axis gets distorted (this doesn't happen with a smaller set of x axis categories - it looks as expected).

I tried playing around with the label styling in the highcharts options (such as rotation, staggerLines), but it doesn't do anything to help fix the issue. The image below shows how my chart looks. Essentially I would want all the labels displatying properly (with text, rotated 90 degrees).

[image]

In the code this is how I have my three axes defined:

```
    xAxis: [
        {type: 'category', title: {text: ""}},
        {type: 'category', labels: {useHTML: true}, title: {text: ""}},
        {type: 'category',title: {text: ""}}
    ],
    yAxis: [
        {title: {text: ""}}, 
        {title: {text: ""}},
        {title: {text: ""}}
    ],
```

i'd greatly appreciate any advice/suggestions. Thanks!

Comment: Please post a working/non-working example where the issue can be seen.

Comment: It is hard to help you without any example. Please, provide us with one.